# How to get a subdirectory in the path of a URL?

Tags: c#, .net, string, url-parsing

I am looking for a way to split a URL, such as http://aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.

How do I get "ccc"? Of course it is possible to split it, but it is not interesting.

Comment: so is there a pattern you want to match?  Say the 3rd part of the url?

Comment: Use the `Uri` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: `string answer = "ccc"` Most elegant possible. Now seriously, could you please provide some more information on how to find that element and in what variations your url may be?

Comment: Why should something like splitting a string be "interesting"? Not sure if trolling but making simple things complicated is a great way to drive your peers batty. Read about incidental complexity and take heed.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "elegant" as much as I would "proper". The `Uri` class provides sufficient functionality for dealing with, you guessed it, URIs.

Answer (score 21):

```
Uri myuri = new Uri("http://aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee");

String str= myuri.Segments[myuri.Segments.Length-3];
```

I think this is the most elegant way you can reach by C#.

**EDIT:**

Actually you can also go with `myuri.Segments[2]` here, there give same result. Also note that this code returns `"ccc/"` as result, so if you want to get `"ccc"` you can go by this(also elegant) way.

```
String str= myuri.Segments[myuri.Segments.Length-3].TrimEnd('/');
```

Comment: +1 can't get much more elegant than that... I just don't understand why you start counting from the end, instead of just taking `myuri.Segments[1]`

Comment: Yes, myuri.Segments[2] is giving same result. I always needed to catch last part of Uri, so it's like an habit :)

Comment: If the author really did want `"ccc"` instead of `"ccc/"`, then add `str = str.TrimEnd('/');` to the above code.  Or, if you have the `System.Web` assembly referenced, you can do `str = VirtualPathUtility.RemoveTrailingSlash(str);`.

Comment: @mesiesta: you're right, it's Segments[2], not Segments[1]. Glancing at the documentation on the MSDN I had not read the bit where it says that Segment[0] is (for whatever reason) always "/"